# select a value of a column reported by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, dynamic-columns

I have a table like this

```
col_name   col_white col_red col_brown col_yellow col_one col_two ....
col_white  1          
col_red              4
col_two                                                   12
....
```

I have to do a select to get this result:

```
col_name     col_value
col_white    1
col_red      4
col_two      12
```

The number of columns is dynamic. How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method is

```
select 'Col_white' as col_name, Col_white from table
union all
select 'Col_red' as col_name, Col_red from table
.
.
select 'Col_two' as col_name, Col_two from table
```

You may need to read about UNPIVOT also

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.col_name, max(t.col_value)
from
(select col_name, col_value
from yourtable) t
group by t.col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this can you try this?

```
SELECT  col_name,CASE WHEN col_name = 'col_white' THEN col_white ELSE CASE WHEN col_name = 'col_red' THEN col_red ELSE CASE WHEN col_name = 'col_two' THEN col_two END
                   END END AS test FROM dbo.Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic sql is the way for this.

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @COL AS NVARCHAR(255)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT  t.col_name
FROM mytable t

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
col_name varchar(50),
col_value varchar(50))

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @COL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT COL_NAME,'+@COL+' FROM mytable where col_name='''+@COL+''''

    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @COL
END

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```